# How to pass shell variable to autogen.sh script

Tags: shell, makefile, configure, autoconf

I calling a autogen.sh script from other Makefile, and this Makefile is called from a shell script, If I set a variable VAR on this more external script I can use-it normally inside this Makefile, really VAR exists and is defined, but when this Makefile runs autogen.sh I cannot use the variable VAR in configure.in file, the only way to get this (or any other variable) is using export command in more external shell.

compile:
    pushd $(DIRNAME); \
    if test ! -e Makefile; then \
        echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH; \
        ./autogen.sh $(CONFIGURE_OPTIONS); \
    fi; \
    make; \
    popd

This is the best way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You could either follow the suggestion from Idelic of passing the variable to `autogen.sh` explicitly as part of the command:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(PKG_CONFIG_PATH)" ./autogen.sh $(CONFIGURE_OPTIONS)
```

or, if you have multiple scripts and commands you call from the `Makefile` and you want to export a bunch of environment variables to any command invoked from this `Makefile`, you could just add these lines to your `Makefile`:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="YOUR_PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export FOO="BLAH"
export BAR="BLAH-BLAH"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the variable explicitly in the `autogen.sh` invocation:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(PKG_CONFIG_PATH)" ./autogen.sh $(CONFIGURE_OPTIONS)
```